# Check which Player got the Highest Roller from Dice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am doing a Ludo Game and currently I need to check which Player got the Highest Number from the Dice and the player which has the highest number goes on the starting position.

Currently I created this method to check which player got the highest number then the player which has the highest numbers runs the method MovePlayer().

Can someone advice me on how can i correctly get the number generated for Player and the number generated for Player 2  cause currently they are the same.

```
public void FirstTurn(){
    int player1Steps = GameObject.Find("Scripts").GetComponent<LevelManager>().randomNumberSteps;
    int player2Steps = GameObject.Find("Scripts").GetComponent<LevelManager>().randomNumberSteps;

    if(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId == "Player1" && player2Played == true)
    {
        if(player1Steps > player2Steps)
        {
            GenerateRandomNumber();
            HighestRollerPlayer1 = true;
        }

    } else if(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId == "Player2" && player1Played == true)
    {
        if(player2Steps > player1Steps)
        {
            GenerateRandomNumber();
            HighestRollerPlayer2 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the Photon Cloud Service since this is a multiplayer Game
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this: [Generate a Random Number that could Step in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804108/generate-a-random-number-that-could-step-in-c-sharp).
you can't use the class that you are using
I would get the number like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int dice1  = rnd.Next(1, 7);
int dice2 = rnd.Next(1,7);
```

in case that we are talking about a regular dice (there are special dices with more or less carats).

It is well explained here: 
[How do I generate a random int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number)

Comment: The question is about Unity, and Unity has his own library with static methods for random numbers, you can do

`int dice1 = Random.Range(1,7);`